# how to load 16 8-bits data and concatenate them to 4 unsigned int?

Tags: assembly, sse, intrinsics, sse2

Is there any elegant way to load 16 8-bits data and concatenate them to 4 unsigned int ?

like follows:

load the following array(16 epi8) by _mm_load_si128() to an __m128i

0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff

and then do some manipulation such that the register(__m128i) becomes 4 epi32,

0x33221100, 0x77665544, 0xbbaa8899, 0xffeeddcc

thanks!

Comment: How is the data laid out in memory?

Comment: The question simultaneously appears to imply that those 16 bytes are not sequentially packed, and that they are. Which is it?

Comment: This is how I interpret your question: You have these bytes stored in memory, with 0x00 in the first byte, 0x11 in the second and so on. You now want them stored as 32-bit little endian numbers (the original configuration would be big endian). Just swap positions 0 and 3, positions 1 and 2, positions 4 and 7, positions 5 and 6, and so on. Do you need an example listing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: do nothing.  After loading, the register is already in your desired state.  (Assuming that `0xbbaa8899` is a typo, and you actually meant `0xbbaa9988`, anyway).

Comment: Sorry, I think I haven't make myself clear. I mean glue the 4 bytes into 1 int in parallel.

Comment: @prgbenz: Right.  You don't need to do anything.  All of the right information is already in the right places; you simply need to interpret it as 4 32-bit integers (which requires a shift in your viewpoint, but no change to the data, and hence no actual operations).

Comment: I can confirm that. This is one advantage of little endian.

Comment: @prgbenz Please be more specific, we need something to work with. Are the bytes stored sequentially in memory when you start? Do you want them back in memory when you're done with them? If so, in which order should these ints be stored? Should you use the same memory location or a different one? If not, I guess you want them in CPU registers. Should they then be in four distinct registers? Which ones?

Answer (score 0):

Just create 4 int pointers and store your m128 in the sequential memory those pointers are targeted at.

Or have a int[4] array and store your m128 into the memory where the array is located then array[0..3] are your 4 integers.

Or if you already have the 16 byte array just cast the memory to integers at indices 0, 4, 8, 12.